# Cython: call function from external C file

Tags: cython

After Cython's "Hello World" and the example of calling a function in the C math libraries [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/external.html#calling-external-c-functions), what I really want to do is to have C code of my own in a separate file and use it from Cython.  Following [this](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#cython-files-depending-on-c-files), I modify the setup.py file:

```
sourcefiles = ['hello2_caller.pyx', 'hello2.c']
```

This is hello2.c (main is just there to compile and test it separately---though that product isn't present for the test:

```
#import <stdio.h>

void f() {
    printf("%s", "Hello world!\n");
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

This is hello2_caller.pyx

```
cdef extern from "hello2.c":
    void f()

cpdef myf():
    f()
```

I get:

```
In file included from hello2_caller.c:219:
hello2.c:3: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
```

So I guess I'm failing to provide a header in some way.. though just feeding setup.py a standard header like 'hello2.h' doesn't work.  Can you point me to a working example or explain what I'm doing wrong.  Thanks.

Comment: Did yeu try specifying the header with `cdef extern from "hello2..h":`. AFAIK the `extern` line should _not_ refer to a C file but to a header file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to help from the Cython users' list [here](http://groups.google.com/group/cython-users/browse_thread/thread/7bc152f90bff3fac).
My writeup [here](http://telliott99.blogspot.com/2010/12/cython-3-my-own-c-source-file.html).

Bottom line:  this is only a warning, that is not fixed by a declaration of f(), but the compiled .so works.  I'm still not sure how you would provide a .h file to Cython or if there is a better way to do this.

And there's a couple of errors:  should be #include, and don't list the .c file in sourcfiles.

Comment: .oOo. Nice one! .oOo.